# Reading form inputs?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, forms, fetch

How would you read the input value ?

On the reacjs site I see very complicated way !!

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

I just want to read the value and submit it via ajax fetch() request. I.e. I don't need to manage bindings, events and such ...

Comment: Event handlers detect when a user is interacting with our app, by clicking or dragging or whatever. This is the absolute goal of the React library, responding to user interactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way by far to read values from html controls is by using an event handler.

```
export default class myComponent extends Component {
    person = {};

    onChange = field => e => {
      this.person[field] = e.target.value;
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <Input
          id="firstName"
          name="firstName"
          autoComplete="firstName"
          autoFocus
          onChange={this.onChange('FirstName')}
        />
      );
    }
  }
```

In the above code snippet we are basically telling react to fire the onChange member on an update of firstName control update. Our method will receive an event e, that has a handle to our control and we can basically probe it's value member to get what's typed in (much like `jquery's $('#element').value()`).

Why is it the easiest method? because it's generic enough to allow you to handle multiple inputs in a react component. Notice that, I'm also instructing React to pass me the control name in addition to the event, and using this method I can basically know exactly which of my inputs (in case of multiple) caused the event to fire.

Comment: why not just something akin to getElementbyID()

Comment: I suppose you can still use the classical document.getElementById but you'd be loosing out so much than using the already provided reactjs mechanism. I think the react way is better. 
[quick note] since react uses a VDOM, I'd just hope that by the time of running the document.getElementById (typically inside componentDidMount()) the elements are in the Virtual. I think it's just too much work

Answer (score 1):

Reading user input value is feasible and recommended via event handlers.

Below example would explain how to read input value and send it to the backend via fetch when Form is submitted

```
  class Test extends Component{
       constructor(props){
           super(props);
           this.state = {
               name: “”
           }
       }

      handleChange = event => {
           this.setState({name: event.target.value});
      }

      handleSubmit = () => {
          //send the value via fetch backend I.e., this.state.name
      }
      render(){
          const { name } = this.state;
          render(
              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                  <label>
                     Name:
                    <input type="text" value={name} onChange={this.handleChange} name="name" />
                 </label>
                 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
              </form>
          )
      }
  }
```